# Rake build - Gemfile not found

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

When I try to build with `rake build` it says it could not locate the Gemfile, even though there is definitely one in the folder I'm executing it in... When I look at how it executes, there is a very mysterious and strange `cd /home/myuser/masterfolder`... I have no idea why it would do that! Here's what happens when I run `rake build --trace` in `/home/myuser/masterfolder/slate`, the folder with my Gemfile in it:

```
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Execute build
cd /home/myuser/masterfolder
bundle exec middleman build --clean
Could not locate Gemfile
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (10): [bundle exec middleman build --clean...]
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:55:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-gh-pages-0.0.3/lib/middleman-gh-pages/tasks/gh-pages.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:125:in `chdir'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:125:in `cd'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `cd'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/middleman-gh-pages-0.0.3/lib/middleman-gh-pages/tasks/gh-pages.rake:59:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => build
```

I'd be shocked if the issue wasn't due to the `cd`, but I just have no idea why it would go up a directory and can't find how to prevent it from that.

Comment: Are you using a gemspec, and if so can you print its contents?

Answer (score 0):

Because of your middleman gem. It handles the Gemfile differently. From the [docs](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/getting-started/):

> **Gemfile**
>
> Middleman will respect a Bundler Gemfile for specifying and
>   controlling your gem dependencies. When creating a new project,
>   Middleman will generate a Gemfile for you which specifies the same
>   version of Middleman you are using. This will lock Middleman to this
>   specific release series (the 3.0.x series, for example). You can also
>   use your Gemfile to use cutting-edge versions of Middleman from GitHub
>   using the :git option. All plugins and extra libraries you use in your
>   project should be listed in your Gemfile, and Middleman will
>   automatically require all of them when it starts.

I have not used that gem, but as per the docs, you might need to do this to build, instead of `rake build`:

```
bundle exec middleman build
```